# Sublime 3: plugin to see when file was last edited?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Anyone know of a plugin that'll display when open files were last edited? That's be *super* useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function (along with many others) is present in [`SideBarEnhancements`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements). Copy the package's default settings to its user settings, then set the following attributes:

```js
"statusbar_modified_time": true,
"statusbar_modified_time_format": "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S",
"statusbar_modified_time_locale": "",
```

Use [`strftime.org`](http://strftime.org/) to learn about all the different format string options. This particular one would read out `2016.05.09 15.49.56`, for example.

Comment: _Excellent_ answer. Thank-you so much.